# sign out current_user after a some time not in use

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails 3 app. I want to be able to kill the user session or to log out after 30 min of not using the app or when the site is closed, and redirect to my login page with some alert. What is the best way to do that? Is there a gem to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you already using a gem for authentication, e.g. Devise or Authlogic, or did you roll your own solution? If rolling your own, add a filter that store the current time in the Session. The filter would then check if the time stored in the filter is greater than your timeout interval and destroy the session accordingly.

Comment: I am using Device. does it have tools to do this?

Comment: Ok dude. I found it in device under Timeoutable https://github.com/plataformatec/devise. can you make it an answer that i will +1 it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Devise, you can use the [Timeout Table](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to expire user sessions.